# Angular frontend requesting Contact Form 7 API to send e-mail doesn't send and the response is site's HTML

Tags: angular, wordpress, email, contact-form-7

My frontend is Angular, and the backend is a headless WordPress. I'm using Contact Form 7's REST API endpoint to send e-mails:

```
sendContactEmail(formData: any) {
  return axios.post<any>(
    // [site.com] is only a placeholder to omit the real domain.
    'https://[site.com]/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/14/feedback',
    formData,
    {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
    }
  );
}

this.email
  .sendContactEmail(data)
  .then(() => {
    f.reset();
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log('error', e);
  })
  .finally(() => {
    this.isLoading = false;
  });
```

The problem is that when I submit the contact form, it seems it is successful because the form is reset. But, no e-mail is sent, and in **Network > Response** tab I do not see any JSON, but my WordPress' HTML.

[image]

I have WP Mail SMTP plugin and I configured with Hostinger's SMTP configuration. I tested and confirmed the test e-mail arrival through the plugin.

All the issues I saw, people had at least a JSON response, so I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

if the url is correct ,then what's the response http status? did you check it in network tab ?
so are you sure you dont need to send login token in  post headers?
like this

```
const USER = WORDPRESS_USER;
const PASSWORD = WORDPRESS_PASSWORD;
const TOKEN = window.btoa(`${USER}:${PASSWORD}`); // Convert Base64
```

```
sendContactEmail(formData: any) {
  return axios.post<any>(
    'https://[site.com]/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/14/feedback',
    formData,
    {
      headers: {
         Authorization: `Basic ${TOKEN}`,
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
    }
  );
}
```

and to check prommise result

```
this.email
  .sendContactEmail(data)
  .then((result) => {
    console.log('result', result);
    f.reset();
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log('error', e);
  })
  .finally(() => {
    this.isLoading = false;
  });
```

Comment: I just omitted it here, certainly it is the correct address in my code.

Comment: so remove the [ ]  ,

Comment: The address in my code is correct, as it should be, and it doesn't have any brackets. I just put it like this in here as a placeholder of some sort, to omit the domain.

Comment: sorry ,please check the updated answer

Comment: The response status is 200, and above I show an image of the response, which for some reason is the HTML of the WordPress site. In all the other examples I found around, the response is a JSON. I am not sure if a token is needed, I didn't see any mention regarding one for CF7.

Comment: when response is html page instead of json and status is 200 ok
, note that the rest api can be redirected to error page when you  are not authenticated or for the another reasons ,please share html pagr response completely

Comment: Well, since my WordPress backend is supposed to be only that, a backend, I completely removed any element of the default theme which comes activated. The HTML that shows was really the whole site, as if visiting it regularly in the browser, seeing the title, first example post, a comment, footer, etc. There was really nothing important in there. But to be honest, I'm thinking about migrating it to a WordPress theme now.

Comment: any way I think you can set "accept" in request header too, headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json',} for test ,I read somewhere when you set accept in request header ,the server should not send back something else, and most certainly not with a 200 OK status code.maybe server raise an error like "not acceptable" then maybe you will find reason of html response instead of json.

Comment: so in your response page ,is it logged in ?  and maybe it's not bad if you test send login token for test :)

Comment: I tried already with `Accept`, and I am not logged in. There is no login functionality. :(

Comment: do you tried to login with passing token in request header as I commented in answer?
I cant understand .do you mean the problem was that you were not logged in?

Comment: I don't think I need any token for that, so I don't have any login functionality, nor I seem to need one. I guess I am just going to learn WP theming and migrate all to WP.